# summing over strings in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

given the dataframe `df` with 1 million rows:

```
   HOUSEID   PERSONID         my_string  
0   20000017    1    0,0,0,1-100,100,100-11,0,0    
1   20000017    1    53,53,53,0,0,0,0,0
2   20000017    1    0,0,0,0,0,12,12,12    
3   20000017    2    1-100-43,43,0,0,0,0,0,0
4   20000017    2    0,0,82-100-41,41,0,0,0,0     
5   20000017    2    0,0,0,53,53,53,0,0    
6   20000017    2    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0    
7   20000231    1    41-100,100-41,41,0,0,0,0,0  
8   20000231    1    0,0,0,41-100,100-1,0,0,0
```

In the column `my_string` there are strings with 8(in my real dataframe 96) codes seperated by ','(sometimes more than one number). For each unique combination of `HOUSEID` and `PERSONID`(a person), I would like to have the numbers combined in a way that '0' values are filled with their corresponding subscript of other row of the same person. Here is the desired output:

```
       HOUSEID   PERSONID         my_string  
   0   20000017    1    53,53,53,1-100,100,100-11,12,12     
   1   20000017    2    1-100-43,43,82-100-41,41,53,53,0,0   
   2   20000231    1    41-100,100-41,41,41-100,100-1,0,0,0
```

In some cases a person ends up with two values for the same subscript. In this case, I would rather the longer code to embed in my final string.

Is this possible?

If yes, how?

Comment: df.groupby agg join

Comment: the 0 condition isn't clear. Do you not want any zeros there?

Comment: @NYC Coder I want them replaced so I won't need the replaced ones. Also, zeros attached to numbers won't be favorable. And other zeros that had no number to replace with should stay in their place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is some discrepancies in your input data, for example the first groups ends up with 9 values or in the second group you have values (other than 0) at the same place in different lines.

Anyway this should do what you want, first `str.split` the column 'my_string' per comma and expand, use `mask` to replace the 0s with nan, perform a `groupby` on both columns, keep the `first` values (not nan) available if any, `fillna` with 0 the one without value,  `agg` with `join` to get the string back and `reset_index`

```
df_ = (df['my_string'].str.split(',', expand=True)
         .mask(lambda x: x.eq('0'))
         .groupby([df['HOUSEID'], df['PERSONID']]) 
         .first()
         .fillna('0')
         .agg(','.join, axis=1)
         .reset_index(name='my_string_agg')
      )
print (df_)
    HOUSEID  PERSONID                        my_string_agg
0  20000017         1      53,53,53,1-100,100,100-11,12,12
1  20000017         2   1-100-43,43,82-100-41,41,53,53,0,0
2  20000231         1  41-100,100-41,41,41-100,100-1,0,0,0
```

Comment: I edited my question. `my_string` has always 8 values, but having values(other than 0) in the same place is actually my input so when I run this code it will lengthen the string. I guess I need to go back a step and form my string differently.

Comment: @alibakhtiari just to understand, let's say the string is 4 elements, and for one group you have 1,2,0,0 and 0,3,4,0. what do you want for the aggregate: 1,2,4,0 or 1,3,4,0 or 1,2,3,4 or 1,2,3,4,0? the current version of the code does 1,2,4,0.